# QPolarChart and QLineSeries error when plotting line over 0/360 degree

Tags: c++, qt, qtcharts

I am trying to create a polar plot with a line series. Sometimes the line will go from ie. 330° to 30°. However the plotted line has an additional point at (0,0).

Is there a way to change that behavior or might that be a bug due to the discontinuity of 360° being equivalent of 0°.

I expect this to be a common scenario, but i did not found anything about this problem online. (However all the examples avoid this 360°/0° transition or start at 0° and end at 360°.)

This is the output i get from the plot:
[image: Polar Plot]

This minimal example was generated with the following code:

```
#include "MainWindow.hpp"
#include "./ui_MainWindow.h"

#include <QChart>
#include <QPolarChart>
#include <QLineSeries>
#include <QValueAxis>
#include <QChartView>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    auto series = new QtCharts::QLineSeries();
    series->append(330,60);
    //series->append(360,60); (with both lines enabled the problem still occurs)
    //series->append(0,60);
    series->append(30,60);
    series->append(60,60);
    series->append(90,60);    

    auto chart = new QtCharts::QPolarChart();
    chart->addSeries(series);

    auto angularAxis = new QtCharts::QValueAxis();
    angularAxis->setTickCount(9);
    angularAxis->setMin(0);
    angularAxis->setMax(360);
    angularAxis->setLabelFormat("%.1f");
    chart->addAxis(angularAxis, QtCharts::QPolarChart::PolarOrientationAngular);
    series->attachAxis(angularAxis);

    auto *radialAxis = new QtCharts::QValueAxis();
    radialAxis->setTickCount(9);
    radialAxis->setMin(0);
    radialAxis->setMax(90);
    radialAxis->setLabelFormat("%.1f");
    chart->addAxis(radialAxis, QtCharts::QPolarChart::PolarOrientationRadial);
    series->attachAxis(radialAxis);

    auto view = new QtCharts::QChartView(chart);

    centralWidget()->layout()->addWidget(view);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: This is not a Qt error. More of a user error. You have set max to 360. From the point you would have to draw a new line or there is a method that takes over this. max is 360 in your representation

Comment: This being a polar chart, I would expect there to be no discontinuity at 360/0 (and i am not exceeding the 360 maximum). In my application I want to display multiple series with legend. But since the series all might have (multiple) such crossings is it still possible to split them up in multiple series at the crossing and still display only one label for the original series?